# Kotlin BigInteger to BigDecimal conversion

Tags: java, kotlin, biginteger, bigdecimal

I'm writing a very simple class and I'm struggling to do some decimal division.

So this is not great code but ...

```
class Rational (val numerator: BigInteger, val denominator: BigInteger) : Comparable <Rational> {

     //ATTEMPT 1
     //val decimalRepresentation: BigDecimal = (numerator.toBigDecimal().div(denominator.toBigDecimal()))//.setScale(5)

     //ATTEMPT 2  
     val decimalRepresentation = (BigDecimal(numerator).div(BigDecimal(denominator))) //.setScale(5)

     override fun compareTo(other: Rational): Int {
        val a = BigDecimal(1.0)
        val b = BigDecimal(2.0)
        val x = a.divide(b) // 0.5
        println ("x: " + x.toString())

        println("this val: " + this.decimalRepresentation)
        println("other val: " + other.decimalRepresentation)

        return when {
           ...
        }
    }
```

So I've tried two ways of converting the BigIntegers into BigDecimals to do the compare and both fail and the maths performs integer division

so

1 / 3 = 0
5 / 6 = 1

I've done a poc in case I'm going mad and x is 0.5.

Could anyone tell me how to fix this (without changing parameter types or converting to a string and back!)

Oddly 1 / 2 is returning 0 as well which seems odd to me as I would expect 0.5 to round to 1 ?  This makes me worry that I'm completely missing a very simple point somewhere!

Comment: You shouldn't convert to BigDecimal for the purpose of comparing. Consider comparing (1/3) with (2000000001/600000000). You have to choose a certain arbitrary scale - say, 5 - when converting to BigDecimal. Both the above numbers would give you 0.33333, yet they're obviously not equal. You should, instead, compare the numerators and denominators directly. Find the lowest common multiple of the two denominators and convert the fractions and compare numerators.

Comment: Yes good point thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the problems lies within [`BigDecimal.div`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/java.math.-big-decimal/div.html). It uses the [RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_EVEN) and the given `scale` of the used dividend `BigDecimal` (which is also stated in the documentation). The other problem is that the `BigInteger` to `BigDecimal`-transformation first sets the scale to 0 (check also [`BigDecimal(BigInteger)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.math.BigInteger))) and therefore it will round without using decimal digits.

Note also that on your sample you used `a.divide(b)` with two `BigDecimal` first and on the actual transformation you used `a.div(b)` with two `BigInteger`-transformed `BigDecimal`. That's a completely different story ;-)

You can solve your issue with one of the following:

Either transform your `BigInteger` using [`toBigDecimal`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/java.math.-big-integer/to-big-decimal.html) and specify a desired `scale`, e.g.:

```
val scale = 10 // decimal digits
val decimalRepresentation = numerator.toBigDecimal(scale) / denominator.toBigDecimal(scale)
```

Or you may want to use `divide` instead and pass the desired scale:

```
val decimalRepresentation = BigDecimal(numerator).divide(BigDecimal(denominator), 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
```

In this case I used 2 decimal digits and I am [rounding up on half (`RoundingMode.HALF_UP`)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_UP).